# Synchronization Fail in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

From [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) I read:

> it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the
>   same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized
>   method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized
>   methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first
>   thread is done with the object.

However, in my simple example there is still a race competition to access the `message` object.

```
public class TestThread extends Thread{
    int thread;
    StringBuilder message;

    public TestThread(int thread, StringBuilder message) {
        this.thread=thread;
        this.message=message;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
                double a=2*2;
            }
            modifyMessage();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void modifyMessage() {
        message.append(thread);
    }
}

public class TestMultithreading {
    static TestThread[] testThreads = new TestThread[5];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("A");
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            testThreads[i] = new TestThread(i, message);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            try {
                testThreads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I expect this to have a *guaranteed* output of a string of length 6. However, from time to time I see something like this:

```
A1034
```

This means that one of the threads failed to modify the object. Can someone explain me, why this happens and propose a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already answered your own question:

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all
>   other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object
>   block

The synchronized only block access on the method of the same object, which means that in every thread the *modifyMessage()* can be called at the same time

What you are looking for is a something like this:

```
   for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
       double a=2*2;
   }
   synchronized(message){
       modifyMessage();
   }
```

Now the method is only call once per StringBuilder instance.

Answer (score 3):

Your methods are all synchronizing on a different object (`this`).

If you change the method to synchronize on a single object, it'll work. For example.

```
public void modifyMessage() {
    synchronized(message) {
        message.append(thread);
    }
}
```